# Use docker run command to pass arguments to CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a nodejs app can take two parameters when started. For example, I can use

```
node server.js 0 dev
```

or

```
node server.js 1 prod
```

to switch between production mode and dev mode and determine if it should turn the cluster on. Now I want to create docker image with arguments to do the similar thing. The only thing I can do so far is to adjust the Dockerfile to have a line

```
CMD [ "node", "server.js", "0", "dev"]
```

and

```
docker build -t me/app .
docker run -p 9000:9000 -d me/app
```

to build and run the docker image.

But If I want to switch to prod mode, I need to change the Dockerfile CMD to be:

```
CMD [ "node", "server.js", "1", "prod"]
```

and I need to kill the old one listening on port 9000 and rebuild the image.
I wish I can have something like

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 environment=dev cluster=0 -d me/app
```

to create an image and run the nodejs command with "environment" and "cluster" arguments, so I don't need to change the Dockerfile and rebuild the docker any more. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I came here and found clever and interesting ideas, however the proper way is with [ENTRYPOINT as shown in this section of the docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Make sure your Dockerfile declares an environment variable [with `ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env):

```
ENV environment default_env_value
ENV cluster default_cluster_value
```

The `ENV <key> <value>` form can be [replaced inline](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement).

Then you can [pass an environment variable with docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/env-environment-variables). Note that each variable requires a specific `-e` flag to run.

```sh
docker run -p 9000:9000 -e environment=dev -e cluster=0 -d me/app
```

Or you can [set them through your compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

```yaml
node:
  environment:
    - environment=dev
    - cluster=0
```

Your Dockerfile `CMD` can use that environment variable, but, as mentioned in [issue 5509](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5509#issuecomment-45243772), you need to do so in a `sh -c` form:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "node server.js ${cluster} ${environment}"]
```

> The explanation is that the shell is responsible for expanding environment variables, not Docker. When you use the **JSON syntax**, you're explicitly requesting that your command bypass the shell and be executed directly.

Same idea with [Builder RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/run) (applies to `CMD` as well):

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell.
> This means that normal shell processing does not happen.
>
> For example, `RUN [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `RUN [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]`.
>
> When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

As noted by [Pwnstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2739334/pwnstar) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873165/use-docker-run-command-to-pass-arguments-to-cmd-in-dockerfile/40873331#comment133920427_40873331):

> When you use a shell command, this process will *not* be started with `id=1`.

Comment: How can I use ENV in the docker file CMD, can you give me an example?

Comment: @Jaaaaaaay `ENV` is a declaration in your `Dockerfile` (read https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env), which will then be valued by `docker run -e myvar=myvalue`

Comment: Beware you use shell command so this process will not be started with id=1

Comment: @Pwnstar Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibililty.

Answer (score 74):

Another option is to use [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) to specify that `node` is the executable to run and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) to provide the arguments. The docs have an example in [Exec form ENTRYPOINT example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example).

Using this approach, your Dockerfile will look something like

```
FROM ...

ENTRYPOINT [ "node",  "server.js" ]
CMD [ "0", "dev" ]
```

Running it in dev would use the same command

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -d me/app
```

and running it in prod you would pass the parameters to the run command

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -d me/app 1 prod
```

---

You may want to omit `CMD` entirely and always pass in `0 dev` or `1 prod` as arguments to the run command. That way you don't accidentally start a prod container in dev or a dev container in prod.

Answer (score 16):

**Option 1) Use ENV variable**

Dockerfile

```
# we need to specify default values
ENV ENVIRONMENT=production
ENV CLUSTER=1

# there is no need to use parameters array
CMD node server.js ${CLUSTER} ${ENVIRONMENT}
```

Docker run

```
$ docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -e ENVIRONMENT=dev -e CLUSTER=0 -me/app
```

**Option 2) Pass arguments**

Dockerfile

```
# use entrypoint instead of CMD and do not specify any arguments
ENTRYPOINT node server.js
```

Docker run

Pass arguments after docker image name

```
$ docker run -p 9000:9000 -d me/app 0 dev
```

Answer (score 6):

The typical way to do this in Docker containers is to pass in environment variables:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -e NODE_ENV=dev -e CLUSTER=0 -d me/app
```

Answer (score 5):

Late joining the discussion. Here's a nifty trick you can use to set default command line parameters while also supporting overriding the default arguments with custom ones:

Step#1 In your dockerfile invoke your program like so:

```
  ENV DEFAULT_ARGS "--some-default-flag=123 --foo --bar"
  CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./my-nifty-executable   ${ARGS:-${DEFAULT_ARGS}}"]
```

Step#2 When can now invoke the docker-image like so:

```
  # this will invoke it with DEFAULT_ARGS
  docker run mydockerimage   

  # but this will invoke the docker image with custom arguments
  docker run   --env  ARGS="--alternative-args  --and-then-some=123"   mydockerimage
```

You can also adjust this technique to do much more complex argument-evaluation however you see fit. Bash supports many kinds of one-line constructs to help you towards that goal.

Hope this technique helps some folks out there save a few hours of head-scratching.

Answer (score 4):

Going a bit off topic, build arguments exist to allow you to pass in arguments at build time that manifest as environment variables for use in your docker image build process:

```
$ docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 .
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps but I have used it this way and it worked like a charm

`CMD ["node", "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229", "--max-old-space-size=256", "/home/api/index.js"]`

Answer (score 2):

I found this at [docker-compose not setting environment variables with flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392753/docker-compose-not-setting-environment-variables-with-flask)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
      image: python:2.7
      environment:
        - BAR=FOO
      volumes:
        - ./app.py:/app.py
      command: python app.py
```

**app.py**

```
import os

print(os.environ["BAR"])
```