# Docker for Windows passing ENV variable to CMD in Dockerfile doesn't work

Tags: docker-for-windows

I have the following instructions in Dockerfile

```
ENV DB_CONN_STRING="Data Source=DbServer;Initial Catalog=Db;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd"
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["powershell", "c:\\RunAll.ps1 -NewConnString", "$DB_CONN_STRING"]
```

When I run this command

```
docker run --rm -d -e DB_CONN_STRING="Test" test
```

DB_CONN_STRING is always empty inside RunAll.ps1.
How can I pass ENV to CMD?

When I use CMD without parameters

```
CMD ["powershell", "c:\\RunAll.ps1"]
```

all works correctly.

RunAll.ps1 code:

```
param(
    [string]$NewConnString = "Data Source=DbServer;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd"
)

New-Item "C:\start_log.txt" -type file -force -value $NewConnString
.\ChangeConnString.ps1 -NewConnString $NewConnString
New-Item "C:\end_log.txt" -type file -force -value $NewConnString

# Run IIS container entry point
.\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc
```

I tried several approaches, exec and shell command styles, $DB_CONN_STRING, ${DB_CONN_STRING} and $(DB_CONN_STRING) styles.

Tried suggestions from these posts:

- [Use docker run command to pass arguments to CMD in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873165/use-docker-run-command-to-pass-arguments-to-cmd-in-dockerfile)
- [How do I use Docker environment variable in ENTRYPOINT array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904682/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array)

Nothing works for me.

Here is an example from Docker log:

```
[16:06:34.505][WindowsDockerDaemon][Info   ] time="2017-03-27T16:06:34.505376100+02:00" level=debug msg="HCSShim::Container::CreateProcess id=0909937ce1130047b124acd7a5eb57664e05c6af7cbb446aa7c8015a44393232 config={\"ApplicationName\":\"\",\"CommandLine\":\"powershell c:\\\\RunAll.ps1 -NewConnString $DB_CONN_STRING\",\"User\":\"\",\"WorkingDirectory\":\"C:\\\\\",\"Environment\":{\"DB_CONN_STRING\":\"Test\"},\"EmulateConsole\":false,\"CreateStdInPipe\":true,\"CreateStdOutPipe\":true,\"CreateStdErrPipe\":true,\"ConsoleSize\":[0,0]}
```

Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22

Comment: Per docker instructions, CMD instruction does not invoke command shell and hence environment variable will not be available for extraction. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd You probably shall consider to switch to "ENTRYPOINT" instead

Comment: I also tried with ENTRYPOINT. By the way, started with it: ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "c:\\RunAll.ps1", "-NewConnString", "${DB_CONN_STRING}"] . Had the same result, then switched to CMD.
Even tried like this: SHELL ["powershell"] ENTRYPOINT c:\RunAll.ps1 -NewConnString  CMD ["$DB_CONN_STRING"]

Comment: Below works for me 
Docker file
`
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
copy hello.ps1 c:\
ENTRYPOINT powershell.exe c:\hello.ps1
`
hello.ps1 is `Write-Output "Environment variable is " + (dir env:)`

I can build an run below and see environment variable being present

`docker run --rm me/me -e "test=lala"`

Comment: Your solution works for me partially. If I use it as is - it doesn't work. But if I add `ENV TEST="test"` in Dockerfile - I'm able to see this environment variable inside container, but I can't reassign it with `docker run --rm me/me -e TEST="lala"` - it always shows "test".

Comment: I'm a bit novice in containers and powershell, and I use this approach to send parameters to the starting container. May be there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for passing ENV to (in this case) ENTRYPOINT command will be

```
ENTRYPOINT powershell c:\RunAll.ps1 -NewConnString %DB_CONN_STRING%
```

So, you need to use the *shell* syntax and windows cmd.exe parameters format. *Exec* syntax of ENTRYPOINT haven't worked for me.
And to pass long string with spaces as parameter you will need to use double different quotes, for example

```
docker.exe run -d --rm -e DB_CONN_STRING="'Data Source=DB2;Initial Catalog=Db;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd'"
```