# node.js + pm2 -- Configuring node_args depending on environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, pm2

Below is a very simple `process.json` to launch a `js` app with pm2.

My goal is to have the process kick off the below `node_args` but only for **non-prod launches**. So, for example, if a certain environment variable is set a certain way, then trigger the node_args, otherwise ignore them.

Is this possible? If not, any workarounds I can do?

```
{
  apps : [
    {
      name      : 'API',
      script    : './app.js',
      node_args: ["--inspect","--debug=0.0.0.0:7000"],
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that it's possible to throw `node_args` at the command line, however the goal is to run this in docker where the "run" command is static to the source image so that's not really viable.

Here is the `CMD` entry in my Dockerfile:

`CMD [ "pm2-docker", "--auto-exit", "--watch", "process.json"]`

Answer (score 3):

You can define multiple declaration of same app, depending on its environment settings.

In your case, your process file definition can be as follows:

**process.json**

```
{
  apps : [
    {
      name      : 'API-DEV',
      script    : './app.js',
      node_args: ["--inspect","--debug=0.0.0.0:7000"],
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development'
      }
    },
    {
      name      : 'API-PROD',
      script    : './app.js',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, if you want to run the `development` version of the app,`CMD` entry of `Dockerfile` will be

```
CMD [ "pm2-docker", "start", "process.json", "--only", "API-DEV", "--auto-exit", "--watch" ]
```

If you don't like the duplicacy, you can use `.config.js` file instead of `json` and define your configuration like this

**process.config.js**

```
const appDefs = [
  {
    "suffix": "prod",
    "node_args": [],
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  },
  {
    "suffix": "dev",
    "node_args": ["--inspect","--debug=0.0.0.0:7000"],
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development"
    }
  }
];

module.exports = {
  "apps": appDefs.map(appDef => ({
    "name": `API-${appDef.suffix}`,
    "script": "./app.js",
    "node_args": appDef.node_args,
    "env": appDef.env
  }))
};
```

Then, `CMD` entry will be

```
CMD [ "pm2-docker", "start", "process.config.js", "--only", "API-DEV", "--auto-exit", "--watch" ]
```

Comment: Thanks. So it seems like I'll need separate images regardless due to the differing `CMD` entry? It would be nice to have the same source image, then when launching the container the environment can be set - is that possible?

Comment: I am no expert in docker, but what i have understood is that, you want to pass different values to your `CMD` entry while executing `docker run` command. In that case, i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873165/use-docker-run-command-to-pass-arguments-to-cmd-in-dockerfile) will solve the problem