# How to run docker container with custom variable (Built with Jenkins)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile, docker-container

I'm trying to run a docker container that uses maven to deploy a java application
Without using docker, the command that I use to deploy is ***"java -jar app-v0.1.jar"***

Since the version of my application tends to change, (app-v0.1, v0.2 ...) what I usually do is running ***"java -jar* *.jar"** (There's always only 1 .jar file in the working folder). This works locally.

However, this seems to be unable to apply when building a Docker container. Here's my dockerfile

---

> FROM openjdk:8
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> COPY *.jar .
>
> CMD ["java", "-jar", "*.jar"]
>
> EXPOSE 8181

---

I can build the docker image from that Dockerfile. But when I try to run the container, I always get the **Error: Unable to access jarfile *.jar.**

I also tried:

> COPY target/*.jar .
>
> RUN file=`find . -name "*.jar" -exec basename {} \;`
>
> CMD ["java", "-jar", "${file}"]

which returns **Error: Unable to access jarfile ${file}**

If I change the "*.jar" to a specific name, for example

> CMD ["java", "-jar", "app-v0.1.jar"]

everything works normally. But clearly I don't want to change my Dockerfile every time there's a code update in my app.

Is there a way in which I can put variables in the Dockerfile, something like "

> CMD ["java", "-jar", "${filename}.jar"]
>   "?

(If this helps: I'm using Jenkins pipeline to automate the docker building process)

Comment: You problem seem a duplicate of the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873165/use-docker-run-command-to-pass-arguments-to-cmd-in-dockerfile

Comment: Normally maven builds your application in "target". So "COPY target/*.jar ." fixed your copy issue. Now you can go back to also run "*.jar" and it will work.

Comment: @Mihai I actually wanted to simplify my question so I just wrote down "COPY **.jar" I do in fact do "COPY target/*.jar" in my dockerfile.

Comment: @Arkadi Thanks. I did read your mentioned question before posting this, but couldn't solve my problem. Maybe I did something wrong when following the approved answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Use `ARG`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg):

```
FROM openjdk:8

ARG filename
ENV jarname=${filename}

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.jar .

CMD java -jar ${jarname}

EXPOSE 8181
```

The use `docker build --build-arg filename=a.jar xxx`

**Solution 2:**

Use `ENV`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env):

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV jarname=""

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.jar .

CMD java -jar ${jarname}

EXPOSE 8181
```

Pass env to when container run `docker run -e jarname=a.jar xxx`

**Solution 3:**

Make `*` work in shell:

```
FROM openjdk:8

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.jar .

CMD java -jar *.jar

EXPOSE 8181
```

Comment: Thanks. Solution 3 works for me. The other 2 don't. But what's the difference when using square brackets in the CMD stage?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I forget only the shell can get the env variable... Update 1&2.

Comment: And if use `[]`, this means it will not use shell. So `*` cannot work. Have a look for this: http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/, also this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a multi-stage build.

Your Dockerfile should be:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8 as build

ARG BUILD_PROFILE=prod

WORKDIR /apps

COPY . .
RUN mvn --activate-profiles ${BUILD_PROFILE} clean install

FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY --from=build /apps/target/*.jar ./
COPY startup.sh ./

RUN chmod +x ./*.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/startup.sh"]
```

And `startup.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -Dspring.profiles.active=${RUN_PROFILE} -jar /app*.jar
```

This way you also build your application when you do a docker build.

**NOTE**
you can also use the command in startup.sh as your entrypoint but I find it cleaner this way.