# Overriding docker cmd when docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am dockerizing a node application.

This is the Dockerfile that I am using:

```
FROM node:10-slim

# Sets environment variable
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Sets work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json
COPY ["package.json", "./"]

# Installs dependencies 
RUN npm install

# Copy working files
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 80

# Starts run command
CMD npm start
```

But then, since I have several .env files, I would like to pass an argument to choose which env file I will use.

Like this

```
npm start -- --env="test"
```

So what I ultimately want is

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 test/nodeapp:1.0 -- -evn="test"
```

How should I override the `CMD` on docker run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form):

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

You can override the `COMMAND` when do docker run as you like, so for you case, if your command in your question is correct, then it is:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 test/nodeapp:1.0 npm start -- --env="test"
```

If still need `-- --env="test"` as you said in comment, you need to use `entrypoint`, then have a look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40875190/6394722)

Comment: thanks! it works! but i still want to "docker run -p 8080:8080 test/nodeapp:1.0 -- -evn="test", should i move "npm start" to entrypoint in dockerfile?

Comment: Then, you should use `entrypoint in dockerfile`, and runtime command will be act as parameters.