# How to read docker run arguments (-p in specific) inside docker container

Tags: docker

I have a requirement where I have to read docker run arguments in my entry command.

docker run -d -p 4058:4058 -p 5800-5805:5800-5805 image_name

Dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine

# some logic in here

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sh start.sh"]
```

In my start.sh file, I want to read the -p value( 4058:4058  5800-5805:5800-5805) of docker run.

Apart from using [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873165/use-docker-run-command-to-pass-arguments-to-cmd-in-dockerfile) variable in docker run, Is there any way to read -p argument in start.sh file.

Comment: If you want to use env variables, it's better to use docker-compose instead.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for now is to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` in your docker aka [dind](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker).

maybe this will be implemented someday , but the issue is from 2014 :). [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3778)

Comment: Though by  giving the container access to /var/run/docker.sock, it is [trivially easy] to break out of the containment provided by docker and gain access to the host machine. Obviously this is potentially dangerous.

Comment: I already added a link to dind Docs "Although running Docker inside Docker is generally not recommended, there are some legitimate use cases, such as development of Docker itself."

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get Bind port inside the container itself unless you mount `/var/run/docker.sock`. but you should not ignore the hight of risk by doing this so better to go with ENV.

> The owner of the docker `/var/run/docker.sock` is root of the host where
>   the container is running, with default group membership to docker
>   group. That's why mounting `var/run/docker.sock` inside another
>   container gives you root privileges since now you can do anything that
>   a root user with group membership of docker can.

So I will suggest going through [docker-security-best-practices](https://dev.to/petermbenjamin/docker-security-best-practices-45ih)

But still, if you want to go and you should aware of the risk then you can do this to get the bind port.

```
docker run --rm -it --name test -p 3000:3000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alpine:latest sh -c "apk add --no-cache curl jq && sh"
```

then run

```
docker exec -it test ash 
curl -s --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock  http:/v1.26/containers/$(hostname)/json | jq \'.NetworkSettings | .Ports | keys\' 
#output:
[
  "3000/tcp"
]
```