# How to run node scripts with a Lambda function based on a docker image

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I will use a Docker image to launch Lambda. and I want to pass arguments at startup.

But in order to launch lambda, I need to add the handler name to the CMD.

How can I solve this?

Lang: Node.js

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:12
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN npm install

CMD ["index.handler"] // success
CMD ["index.handler","arguments"] // Error: entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument
```

index.js

```
exports.handler = async () => {
  console.log(process.argv[2]);
}
```

Comment: what is the runtime language you are using, and can you update the question with complete commands

Comment: I updated the information. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873165/use-docker-run-command-to-pass-arguments-to-cmd-in-dockerfile